# Date CAST in SQL Server throwing conversion failed for a date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am experiencing a very unique cast error I don't understand why it happens with some dates and only in one particular case.
First at all, I cannot change the current code, it's a dynamic query from a legacy application and it's the result of queries to different tables to assemble the query I am having troubles with.

The error is a classic 'conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string'.

At the beginning I thought it was a classic file naming error, we obtain the date from the file name in the format YYYYMMDD, the file has prefix and suffix and it's always formatted like that. It was pretty common to get wrongly formatted dates but it doesn't happen anymore. The issue is interesting because it only happens in 1 case for some dates that do not look like errors, for example, 20201105 which is basically translated to 11/05/2020 (US Format with month first).

This is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(LEFT(REPLACE(FileName, 'XXYYY_,''),8) AS DATE) AS MyDate FROM Mytable
```

The file name in this case is XXYYY_20201105.txt
Why the top 1? Well, it is a very bad design, there are many rows with the same value and it has to take only one to determine the date.

The most interesting part of it, when it fails I can "fix" the error just adding one more column:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(LEFT(REPLACE(FileName, 'XXYYY_,''),8) AS DATE) AS MyDate, AnotherColumn
FROM Mytable
```

This query, just adding a column, doesn't fail. That's the weirdest part. I am trying wrap my head around what is the difference between obtaining ONE column and TWO columns. When I add any other column it seems to make the issue disappear.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You will probably find that it is looking at different rows due to indexing, the row you are getting is invalid. Use `SELECT TOP 1 MyDate, TRY_CAST(...` and you will see. Really, you need to remove the `.txt` also in order to get a valid format

Comment: It is not, all the rows have the same value, they are cleaned up and re-inserted every time with the same exact value. I will try the TRY_CAST but I don't think it is indexing.

Comment: Very interesting. TRY_CAST works, CAST doesn't in this case. Very strange.

Comment: Now do `TRY_CAST` with and without the extra column, and see which row comes back. Possibly (but unlikely) there is something more underlying, such as the conversion being done (and failing) by the storage engine during prefetch.

Comment: You got a point. Still VERY confused for the results. If I add the ID only as an extra column it fails, if I add more columns it doesn't. TRY_CAST never fails, CAST does in some situations. I think I will go with TRY_CAST which requires code change but pretty small.. I wish I could figure out the real underlying issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So does `TRY_CAST` return null for any of the rows? Probably something like a non-printable character in one of the rows, which won't convert. Adding more columns is causing the optimizer to pick a different row to output.

Comment: No, TRY_CAST works always when CAST doesn't. It is a very rare problem I cannot determine.

Comment: I'm very interested in this. `TRY_CAST` should always return null where `CAST` would fail. Can you share the full table via pastebin.com or something? Also [edit] in you rexact query (lloks like you got a syntax error currently)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the real table content because it is very sensitive. I will edit the post, I wrote the code from the top of my head not through copy/paste. Thanks again.